# How to link .h files in vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new in C++ and I have three files **main.cpp**, **npc.cpp** and **npc.h**. I tried to run it and this error appears:

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: npc.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include "npc.h" 
  |          ^~~~~~~
```

**`compilation terminated.`**

Here is my **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "npc.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NPC Tom(100, 45);

    Tom.Stats();

    return 0;
}
```

And **npc.h**:

```
#ifndef NPC_H
#define NPC_H

class NPC
{
public:
    NPC();
    ~NPC();
    NPC(int life, int level);
    void Stats();

private:
    int m_life;
    int m_level;
};

#endif /*NPC_H*/
```

And finally, **npc.cpp**:

```
#include "npc.h"
#include <iostream>

NPC::NPC()
{
}

NPC::~NPC()
{
}

NPC::NPC(int life, int level) : m_life(life), m_level(level)
{
}

void NPC::Stats()
{
    std::cout << "This npc has " << m_life << " and is at level " << m_level << "." << std::endl;
}
```

Do someone knows to **Run** this code with the header file without having any errors?

Comment: Set the include path in your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json`. Also you will have to modify the default tasks.json to get it to build both .cpp files.

Comment: if npc.h is in the same folder as main.cpp and npc.cpp I would expect it to find the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution to this problem is to execute the following command:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp npc.cpp && ./main
```

This will tell the compiler to link `npc.cpp` file with the main executable. The error was producible in my machine when I didn't include `npc.cpp` in the command line:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp && ./main
```

This threw an error about undefined references to the class member functions which were **defined** in `npc.cpp`.

Comment: And how about the **npc.h** file?

Comment: @noob1 You don't need to add header files during compilation. They're found by the compiler during compilation.

Comment: And what if I put the header file in a folder then?

Comment: @noob1 You'll need to define the include statement: `#include "folder/extra_folder/source.h"`.

Comment: I don't know why but It keeps showing me the error.

Comment: @noob1 Make sure you've placed all the files in the same directories if you're still not getting your error fixed by that command.

Comment: If the OS is Windows, make sure that `npc.h` is not named `npc.h.h`. With the default hiding of extensions it is possible to get confused like this.

Comment: If that was the problem I suggest you turn off the "hide extensions for known types" option in the file explorer of windows. [https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/)